# Single line expression to branch off of and clear a boolean flag?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

The other day, a colleague noticed the common pattern he was doing of:

```
if (someBooleanFlag)
{
    someBooleanFlag = FALSE;
    ...do some more stuff...
}
```

basically, a clear-on-read latch. And asked if I knew of a clever way to test the flag and clear it as a one-liner, so he could get rid of the boilerplate someBooleanFlag = FALSE; bit. Questions about whether this is good style or not aside, I found the best I could do for him was a something like

```
#define TESTANDCLEAR(var) (var ? var-- : 0)
```

This makes the assumption that ONLY 1 and 0 are being used, and it doesn't work on bitmasks either. I figured I'd turn to the Wizards of the Stack, to see if there was some better way and other technique that could be used.

(Again, no need to discuss whether the style of doing a TESTANDCLEAR() expression is bad or good, it was more of the academic exercise if we actually could do it, and how generally)

Comment: Which way is clearest and easiest to understand for the next developer who has to read the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to make the 0/1 assumption, even with the approach you already have. Assignments are expressions that return a value, so you could define that macro as:

```
(var ? !(var = false) : false)
```

Or, you could use the comma operator:

```
(var ? ((var = false), true) : false)
```

Which would help if you wanted this to work with a bitfield testing for the `N`th bit:

```
(((var & (1 << N)) ? ((var = var & ~(1 << N)), true) : false)
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I'm actually not sure I had ever internalized the comma operator in C, you just don't see it that often.

Answer (score 3):

Ugly, but I think this should work:

```
if (someBooleanFlag && !(someBooleanFlag = !someBooleanFlag))
```

For the love of God never do this in production code.